# AWS.Amplify is not a constructor

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to make a simple lambda function to do a basic text translation, but when I try to post it to my database, I get the error message `AWS.Amplify is not a constructor` any help? I'm using the aws website to code it so its nodejs.

```
console.log('Loading function');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const translate = new AWS.Translate({ apiVersion: '2017-07-01' });
const API = new AWS.Amplify();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    const params = {
      SourceLanguageCode: 'en', /* required */
      TargetLanguageCode: 'es', /* required */
      Text: 'Hello World', /* required */
    };

    const data = await translate.translateText(params).promise();

    createSite(data.TranslatedText);

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack);
  }

  function createSite(site) {
  return API.post("sites", "/sites", {
    body: site
  });
}
};
```

Comment: You need to import the amplify.js.

Comment: @SangamBelose How?

Comment: import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';

Comment: @SangamBelose The I get the error, unexpected token import

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the node.js project locally and then add the amplify.js through webpack.

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "amplify-js-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Amplify JavaScript Example",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.17.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack && webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "build": "webpack"
  }
}
```

And then do your existing code by importing the amplify.js in your app.js / handler function of lambda of node project as below:

```
import Amplify, { API } from "aws-amplify";
// then write your existing code.
```

Then build your project and deploy it to AWS lambda by either ways:

1. Directly uploading it to function
2. Uploading to S3 bucket and then give reference of that bucket in lambda function.

Reference: [amplify.js docs](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/start)